# If we are supplying energy continuously, why will the electrons jump down to the lower state?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

We know in a flame test an electron goes into excited state. When it jumps down to a lower energy state, we can see the color of the flame if it's in our visible region.

My question: we are supplying energy continuously, so why will the electrons jump down to the lower state?

Comment: The atom/ions are escaping the hottest part of the flame. Moreover, likely there are transient phenomena.

Comment: They return to their original state as electrons in higher energy levels are more unstable. They give out the energy absorbed in the form a radiation.

Comment: @Bastardane but im  suppling  energy ..so why they give out their energy absorbed ?

Comment: You're not supplying energy to only one electron. This excitation - de-excitation process takes place continuously. The unstability in excited state causes them to return to ground state

Comment: What do you mean by that? How would you accomplish this? How exactly do you picture the interaction between your excited system and whatever supplies that energy in whatever (see first 2 questions) way?